# Can you shield bash for AOO?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, shield

Are you allowed to make attacks of opportunity with a shield bash?
Or is a better question for this, can/do you threaten with a shield?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

PFSRD [Equipment section](http://www.paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/equipment.html) says:

> You can [bash](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/equipment.html#shield-bash-attacks) with a [heavy or light] shield instead of using it for defense.

Both heavy and light shields are listed as meleé weapons with the only special rule being that an attack with one removes the shield bonus until your next turn.

The [Attacks of Opportunity section](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#attacks-of-opportunity) says:

> **Threatened Squares:** You threaten all squares into which you can make a melee attack, even when it is not your turn.

Because you can attack with a shield, you threaten with a shield.

Comment: @Balacertar Uh... where are you finding that? I was all set to agree and edit, but in looking the links up, I don't find anything in equipment, combat or AoO's... The only nonproficiency penalty for attacks I see is -4 to hit.

Comment: @Balacertar I get that it's a martial weapon, and nonproficient use as such would incur a -4 penalty to hit. But reread that FAQ entry: it says '...without a nonproficiency penalty..." and the answer reiterates that a nonproficient cleric bashes at -4. It's important to know, but has no bearing on whether or not you *can* bash, merely whether or not you *should* bash. :)

Comment: Ok, it is your answer after all, I just thought that related bit of information can be of use, because I know most people do not realize it is a martial weapon.